# How is it that in the US there so many laws being enforced that the majority of people never agreed to?

Tags: democracy, one-person-one-vote

There are too many examples to list, but here are a few:

1. When you are driving in your car with more than a few hundred dollars in cash, if you get pulled over and the police see it, they can take it even if you were doing nothing wrong. And then you have to pay a bunch of money (more than what the police took in the first place, by design it would seem) just to even ATTEMPT to go to court and MAYBE get SOME of it back.
2. Marijuana being classified as a schedule 1 drug.
3. Apartments can require potential renters to prove that they currently have a job that pays a certain amount, despite the fact that the persons credit might be good enough already, and/or that they may have enough money in the bank to cover the entire length of the lease.
4. A business owner such as a bar or restaurant is legally required by the state to not allow smoking on its premises, even if it might lose a substantial amount of money by doing so.

All of these are examples of laws that exist and are enforced but if you went around randomly asking real people how they felt about these laws the VAST majority of them would certainly tell you that they did not vote for any of these nor do they think these are fair.  Yet, somehow we are supposed to believe that we live in a democracy?  How can this be?

Comment: Also it is interesting why some of the laws you mentioned have been recently pushed onto other countries such as Russia, Belarus, Ukraine etc. For instance, prohibition of smoking so that they prohibited smoking everywhere, including trains, stops, airports (and closed smoking-rooms), bars and retauraunts and office buildings (requiring closure of all smoking rooms). Similar measures regarding alcohol, but in opposite direction: you can smoke only outdoors but drink only indoors. The same is with rising age of consent etc.

Comment: In a free market or democracy, the govt has no business telling a business owner how to run their business.  It's up to the business owner to choose the rules for their establishment, and then the customers can choose not to patronize the establishment if they dont like the rules.  That is how a free market is supposed to work.  But thats not how it actually works in many places that claim to be democratic.  To those govts, you have a choice:  Stop bullying people or stop characterizing yourself as a democracy.  You cant have it both ways....

Comment: Is this a question or a rant?

Comment: Youre the boss.  It's whatever you say, sir.

Comment: Also, "democratic" and "free market" aren't synonyms by any definition whatsoever, democracy doesn't mean "direct democracy," and your assumption about what the "VAST" majority think is dead wrong in at least 2 cases (according to actual polls, the majority in the US support public smoking bans, virtually no one thought marijuana should be legal until quite recently; also, civil forfeiture started in the crime waves of the 1980s and was sold as the very popular "don't let criminals pay their fancy lawyers with ill-gotten gains", and point 3 is the *absence* of a law).

Comment: I never said I thought that the VAST majority thought marijuana should be legal.  Read more carefully, I said schedule 1. Also, the general public has no right to vote on the rules at a business owners establishment - they only have a right not to patronize it.

Comment: @ModernDaySlave You appear confused about the definition of "democracy." Nowhere in the definition does it say what the public has no "right" to vote on; in fact, any attempt to keep the majority from voting to implement some law is a restriction on democracy (and those are necessary, but they're *not* core features of democracy). Also, I don't see why you state your opinions about what the public has a right to vote on as though they're undisputed fact; they are in fact very disputed.

Comment: Only a fascist would believe they have the right to tell a business owner how they can run their business.  A reasonable person may disagree with the way the business owner is running his business, and they would "vote" against it by not patronizing it.  This should just be common sense.

Comment: We only vote for representatives, not directly on laws, except in the case of initatives and referendums. Probably because the legislature gave up their right to make laws by allowing the bureaucracy to make the laws for them. Now you only have the APA (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_Procedure_Act) to protect you against the government bureaucrats.

Comment: @moderndayslave nearly every nation has rules and regulations as to how businesses can operate. Your "only fascists" comment is laughably absurd.

Comment: @ModernDaySlave Wouldn't that mean that letting landlords ask whatever they want from prospective tenants (your point 3) is also common sense? It's easy to resort to this sort of naive appeals to “freedom” to dispose of rules you don't like but since you think the government and/or the people should intervene in the landlord/tenant situation, you obviously do not actually believe that businesses should never be regulated.

Comment: Once you realise that there is no overarching principle at play here, your question simply becomes “Why doesn't everybody agree with me?”, which is not particularly interesting.

Comment: @ModernDaySlave - frankly, I'm too lazy to read the whole thread. But as a very libertarian leaning person who is allergic to tobacco smoke, I can only say one thing: your right to swing your fist (in this case, smoke) ends where my face starts (in this case, exposure of my libertarianish self to your smoke). Another view of this is that there are economic externalities on me (paying taxes for tobacco smoke induced diseases) which means it's not just a question of your freedom.

Answer (score 5):

To answer you specific examples.

1. This is called [civil forfeiture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_forfeiture_in_the_United_States), it has become more abused in modern times, but the practice dates back to the founding of the U.S. It was intended to serve as a prevention tool against criminals that were hard to catch (organized crime bosses), and through the war on drugs has become an important income tool for many police departments across the U.S.
2. The FDA was given the power to classify drugs as they see fit as the define what the classifications mean as well. The war on drugs and other lobbying efforts may have been part of why the FDA classified it as it did, but they were given the power to do so.
3. This is contract law and the U.S. government doesn't interfere much in contract law. Discrimination is allowed in the U.S. despite the popular belief to the contrary, unless it is based upon a [protected class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_class) (Race, Sex, Age, Religion being the primary classes).
4. Public Support for public smoking bans is actually the [majority](http://www.gallup.com/poll/174203/americans-favor-ban-smoking-public-not-total-ban.aspx) in the U.S. These laws were largely a result of the push to eliminate [second-hand smoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_smoking) through the 90s and early 2000s.

To explain how such laws are created in the more general sense, the answer is simply the U.S. is a republic. Congress may pass any laws it wants regardless of public opinion, public support is only a factor in electing representatives which are not legally bound to their voters will. In theory representatives that vote against public opinion would be voted out in the next election, but the public is rarely informed in such cases and has a short memory so a few months of pandering to votes is generally enough to win reelection.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this is simple- the view looks different from on high. In the US there is a class of political elites. If you asked them these questions, they'd likely be more in line with what's put in place.

It's important to remember that the US isn't a direct democracy- you live in a country where the people don't make the laws, and they don't even directly elect their leaders. The fact is that nowadays people only get into office with the support of two groups that have different opinions to most- the first being other politicians and the other being big business. You don't get into office unless you promise to do what they want, so even if you had the best of intentions you have to pander to them.

Many of the opinions such people hold aren't necessarily reasonable- the view of Marijuana as more harmful than it really is, is likely held because they have no experience with it nor with anyone who does have experience with it. Any experiences that have an impact are likely to be bad (because good experiences don't affect you in the same way). Laws that disproportionally affect the least wealthy portions of society are far more likely to go through than those that affect everybody because **everybody includes politicians.**

There's another point to consider. **These people have facts and statistics on their side a lot of the time.** Smoking bans occur because smoking does real damage, even if people don't realise it. This is backed up by facts and statistics that they have available to them. This is actually a case where removal from everyday Americans is perhaps a good thing. It allows them to make decisions without being biased by common views on the subject.

Of course, that goes the other way. Sometimes their views don't accord with the facts; as mentioned above, their views on some topics are skewed. So sometimes they ignore the facts.

It's a double-edged sword that's a problem for all modern societies- the fact that we have people in office who don't necessarily have any connection with the common man because they live in a completely different subculture. They have better information a lot of the time, but often they're skewed by that subculture's perceptions of a topic. These views might be substantially different, such as how, here in the UK, it seemed like the entire country objected to the decision to join the war in Iraq after 9/11.

It sucks. But sometimes you have to accept that they probably know better than you on some subjects. If you read into something seriously and still believe they're wrong and it's something you care about, minds can always be changed. If there's a law they're enacting and you don't like it, write to people, raise money for adverts if enough agree with you. Get people united against it to change people's minds. Sometimes, those same facts and figures are on the side of the people and you just need to show it to the powers that be.

That is, after all, what's happening with regards to gay rights and marijuana. It just takes time and persistence.

Comment: Marijuana *is* harmful (and having stunned people wandering around in legality is even more harmful)

Comment: Marijuana is harmful to who? The people using it, shouldn't that be their choice? Isn't making drugs illegal also harmful (gang wars in the 80s). BTW, second-hand smoke isn't really that dangerous. You are more likely to die from living inside a building or eating bananas.

Comment: Just like tobacco, it's also harmful for the surroundings people as well. And yes having someone smoking (no matter what) next to you it not only dangerous (it's not because you don't die instantly it's safe), but also and first of all  **extremely unpleasant**, especially for children.

Comment: @Bregalad he didn't say it wasn't harmful.

Comment: While it's true that they often have statistics on their side, it's as true that they often ignore them much of the time...willingly or otherwise.

Comment: @user1873, not really that dangerous? http://www.webmd.com/smoking-cessation/effects-of-secondhand-smoke

Nothing I've said here goes against the scientific consensus. And that's the point- that sometimes they have views that do go against the facts as espoused by the scientific community.

Comment: I've edited to make the point that sometimes they ignore the facts, as I realised it doesn't explicitly say that.

Comment: @Bregalad, I stand by my statement. SHS just isn't that dangerous. The EPA estimated lung cancer deaths [at about 7k](http://www.epa.gov/smokefree/pubs/strsfs.html), where radon deaths from breathing indoor air were [estimated at 21k](http://www.epa.gov/radon/risk_assessment.html). This fear of SHS reminds me of people who are afraid of having their kids visit a home with guns, but have no issues with having their kids go to a house with a pool (drowning more likely to kill them). If you don't like SHS, we have these things called legs, walk away.

Comment: @user1873, the question of whether second-hand smoke is actually harmful is off-topic. The fact is that the consensus, both in the scientific community and politicians is that it is. That's what affects policy.

Comment: @PointlessSpike, you should remove this then, " Smoking bans occur because smoking does real damage, even if people don't realise it. This is backed up by facts and statistics that they have available to them" **Unless you would support a ban on living indoors too**